# How to prove that $1-\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2^{n+1}(2^{n-1}+1)} \geq \frac{2^{N-1}+1}{2^N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation

The question is in the title. Numerical computation suggests the result is true, but I don't know how to prove it rigorously.

Comment: What would nice too will be to identify the limit of (lhs-rhs) when $N \to \infty$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I suspect the LHS does not have a closed form limit, though I would certainly welcome being shown otherwise!

Comment: There is a closed form for the LHS and for its limit too.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Oh, great! Please feel free to share more.

Comment: See also closely related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3716705/does-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n-1-12n12n-11-have-a-closed-form

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it, but my answer isn't very slick. Improvements are very welcome.

Rearranging, it suffices to show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2^{n+1}(2^{n-1}+1)} \leq \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^N}.$$
Now, I can verify this inequality by hand for $N \in \{1,2\}$. Let $N > 2$. First observe that
$$\frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2^{n+1}(2^{n-1}+1)} < \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}.$$
In particular, for $n=1$, the LHS is $0$ while the RHS is $1/4$. Thus,
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2^{n+1}(2^{n-1}+1)} + \frac{1}{4} < \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} < \frac{1}{2},$$
which implies
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2^{n+1}(2^{n-1}+1)} < \frac{1}{4} < \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^N}$$

Answer (score 1):

First note that $\frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2^{n+1}(2^{n-1}+1)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{2^{n-1}+1}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ (an alternative form). Also the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+1}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=2<\infty$ and hence it converges by the comparison test. Since $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}-(\frac{1}{2^{N+1}})$ we have $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2^{n+1}(2^{n-1}+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{N+1}}<\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{N+1}}=\frac{1}{2}(2-\frac{2}{2^{N}})-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{N+1}}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2^{N}}+\frac{1}{2^{N+1}}$

Comment: Thanks! This is nice but doesn't actually seem simpler than the proof I gave. Do you think there's anything wrong with my proof?

Comment: Also the result should be $< \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^N}$, so I'm afraid the last steps of your proof don't work

Comment: Yes I've changed it to what I had before. I think your proof is fine.