# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2^{n+1}(2^{n-1}+1)}$ have a closed form expression?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

It's clear that the series converges by comparison with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$, but beyond that I am not sure what can be said.

Comment: It's easy to manipulate the series into an expression involving $$\sum\frac1{2^n+1}$$ but I can't find any references (or proofs) that this does or doesn't have a closed form, I'm afraid.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha doesn't think so...

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Couldn't find the sequence in OEIS either. Could be that this sequence just hasn't been studied or something, but I doubt it'd have a closed form.

Comment: WA gives $\sum\limits_{n=0}^m \frac{2^n - 1}{2^n (2^n + 1)} = -\frac{2 \psi_2^{(0)}\left(m - \frac{i \pi}{\log(2)} + 1\right)}{\log(2)} + 2 m + 2^{-m} + \frac{2 \psi_2^{(0)}\left(1 - \frac{i \pi}{\log(2)}\right)}{\log(2)} - 1$ where $\psi_q^{(z)}$ is the [q-digamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin ... Note that the $q$-digamma $\psi_q^{(0)}$ is defined only for $|q|<1$.

Comment: We just had this series earlier today.

Comment: I think the first appearance has been deleted, but there's also this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3716642/how-to-prove-that-1-sum-n-1n-frac2n-1-12n12n-11-geq-fra – if you're going to post such closely related questions, you should link each to the other.

Answer (score 5):

The first step I would suggest is to split the sum into two:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2^{n-1}-1}{2^{n+1}(2^{n-1}+1)} = \frac{2^n-(2^{n-1}+1)}{2^{n+1}(2^{n-1}+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}+1}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}.
\end{equation}
Thus the initial sum is simply equal to
\begin{equation}
S = \frac{1}{2}\underbrace{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n+1}}_{S_1}-
\underbrace{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}_{S_2}.
\end{equation}
Obviously, $S_2 = \frac{1}{2}$. For the first one, WolframAlpha gives
\begin{equation}
S_1 = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n+1} = -1 +\frac{1}{\log 2}\psi_{1/2}^{(0)}\left(\frac{-i\pi}{\log(2)}\right).
\end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
S = \frac{1}{2\log 2} \psi_{1/2}^{(0)}\left(\frac{-i\pi}{\log(2)}\right)-1.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Is there some simple closed form lower bound for $S$? I'm not familiar with these q-digamma functions. Obviously $S$ is something less than $1/2$, but it would be helpful to understand a bit better how much less than $1/2$.

Comment: Actually, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2%29QPolyGamma%280%2C+%28%28-i%5Cpi%29%2Flog%282%29%29%2C+1%2F2%29&assumption=%22i%22+-%3E+%22ImaginaryI%22&assumption=%7B%22FunClash%22%2C+%22log%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Log%22%7D) gives a value $> 3/4$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe what you wrote for $S_1$ is not quite right. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=76695dd7d98ac2e50a52616ab7051e70).

Comment: [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2%29%28-log%282%29+%2B+QPolyGamma%280%2C+%28%28-i%5Cpi%29%2Flog%282%29%29%2C+1%2F2%29%29%2Flog%282%29+-+1%2F2) suggests $S > 1/8$.

Comment: @user435571 I have corrected all the mistakes. Now it looks fine. The total sum is approximately 0.13225.